# Refresh page only if no user interaction or input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently working on a little web app, which also has a little, minimalistic function for a chat.

In that chat, one user can write to another user by typing something into an input field and pressing enter or submiting the form by clicking a button.

Now to check for new messages, I thought of simply refreshing the page every x seconds, for example every 20 seconds. I also thought of using AJAX, however, then I would also need to rebuild the complete chat, which would basically use the same amount of data etc, so it doesn't really make anything better (correct me, if I'm wrong).

Back to the refresh idea, I used the following code (found in another StackOverflow thread) in order to prevent the page to refresh, when the user is typing in that moment:

```
(function(seconds) {
    var refresh,       
        intvrefresh = function() {
            clearInterval(refresh);
            refresh = setTimeout(function() {
               location.href = location.href;
            }, seconds * 1000);
        };

    $(document).on('keypress click', function() { intvrefresh() });
    intvrefresh();

}(15)); // amount of seconds
```

Now that works fine, but I have 2 "problems" with it.

1. it generates a lot of javascript calls. When typing a little text into the input field, everytime I type a letter, it calls the function which refreshes the interval. Is this "pratically" useable, also on a smartphone, or are those too many JS calls then?
2. Page shouldn't refresh, if something is written inside the input (user typing something, going somewhere for 5 minutes and wants to proceed). I tried to just put

   `if($('#newMessageInput').val()=="")`

into the `intvrefresh` function in order to always check, if nothing is written in the input before refreshing. However, it doesn't work, because then, it doesn't set the interval anymore...

Can you give me an idea of what to do in order to get the behaviour I need? Would AJAX be better anyway? What would be the best way to do it then?

Comment: If you're building a chat the best way to do it is by using Websockets. Refreshing the page or making an AJAX request every N seconds are not workable solutions. Then you don't even need to worry about solving the problem you have.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I might want to add, that usually, the user will only have max. 100 or 200 messages with another user, so its not the massive traffic or something... I think using websockets would be a bit "overkill" for that
Basically its just a function to contact the administrator of the page and write a few lines with him in order to discuss a problem or suggest something...

Comment: It's not overkill at all. It's the right tool for the job. Can you imagine how infuriating it would be for your users to have the page refreshing all the time when you're trying to read a comment? Or alternatively, how badly it'll affect server load. Right now, with AJAX or refreshing the page, you're using a hammer to knock in a screw.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan did you read my edit in the comment? Bascially its like a chat for "support", would you also use the sockets for a "helpdesk-like-chat"?

Comment: Absolutely yes, 100%

Comment: Okay, I'll think about that and check it out... However, I'd still like to get the current solution working first......